# Knapsack and graph optimization

Tags: algorithm, graph, knapsack-problem

I asked this question in mathstackexchange but I think it's more appropriate to be here...

Check the link below
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1359996/knapsack-in-graph
It's a question from a job interview. They had five questions. To reach the next you must answer the previous. This was the first question and I failed in the very beginning.

**EDIT:** (Adding the question)

"You are given an undirected connected weighted graph with n nodes. The weight function represents transportation costs. In each node there are some items with given volume and price. There are totally M items. You have a knapsack with volume W and your goal is to traverse from node A to node B collecting some of the items and maximizing your profit. You can take a given item only once."

Check this example with `W=16`:

[image]

You can take `(6,3)` from A and `(10,8)` from B making profit 3+8−2=9.
Another choice is `(6,3)`,`(3,5)` from A and `(5,5)` from B with profit 11.
You can also take `(3,5)`,`(8,4)` from A and (5,5) from B with profit 12.
However the best decsion is to take `(6,3)` from A, `(4,7)` from C, `(6,20)` from D, then go back to A and go to B.
Another best route is `(3,5)` from A, `(6,20)` from D and `(5,5)` from B.
They both need 6 for transportation costs, so the total profit is 24.

Comment: While you are posting it to all the stackexchanges - http://cs.stackexchange.com/ since you're not actually sitting at a computer coding this may be more appropriate, and might also be able to give you better answers.